# Using Thrift for PHP to C++ translations

Tags: php, c++, thrift

I was wondering if anyone had any experience with thrift and could provide an example of taking a PHP array (or object) and translate it into a C++ array (or object). Either that or point me to documentation on how to do this in PHP (which is incomplete on their website!)

Thanks!
Matt Mueller

Comment: If you're looking for a Thrift tutorial, you can check my full tutorial about thrift in [my blog](http://www.alireza-noori.com/programming/thriftpart-one-introduction/)

Answer (score 2):

There's more documentation in the [Thrift calculator tutorial](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/0.2.0/tutorial/tutorial.thrift). In particular, Thrift's "list" type is likely to be represented as an array in PHP and C++. You can see for yourself how each language binding serializes these data structures in the "protocol" implementations of each language.

Regards,
Jeff